# How to print an HTML table using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

This is my code:

```
<table class="video_table">
  <% count = 0 %>
  <tr>
  <% @f_videos.each do |f_video| %>
     <td><%= f_video.name %></td>
     <td><%= f_video.date_added %></td>
     <td><%= f_video.views %></td>
     <% count +=1 %>
     <% if count == 4 %>
         </tr>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

at each 4 videos placed I want the table to switch row. So I implemented a counter.
But it is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, it'll only equal `4` once, since you don't reset it. Generally this type of task is done with the `%` (modulo) operator so it doesn't have to be reset.

Comment: Please indent your code properly, and please don't use "thx".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your count will only be set to 4 once.

Instead of `if count == 4` use `if count % 4 == 0`

This will repeat the `</tr>` for each multiple of 4

---

Alternatively, you could skip using the count variable and use `each_with_index` to get the same result

```
<table class="video_table">
<% @f_videos.each_with_index do |f_video, i| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= f_video.name %></td>
    <td><%= f_video.date_added %></td>
    <td><%= f_video.views %></td>
    <% if (i+1) % 4 == 0 %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
</table>
```

---

**Even better!** [`each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)

```
<table class="video_table">
<% @f_videos.each_slice(4).to_a do |slice| %>
  <tr>
    <% slice.each do |f_video| %>
      <td><%= f_video.name %></td>
      <td><%= f_video.date_added %></td>
      <td><%= f_video.views %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: thx! my code had also another error, <tr> should be above <% @f_videos.each do |f_video| %>

Comment: @TestTest see the `each_slice` example; I think this the best way to do this.

Comment: Also, welcome to StackOverflow! If this answer worked for you, please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
<table class="video_table">
<% @f_videos.in_groups_of(4) do |group| %>
  <tr>
    <% group.each do |f_video| %>
      <td><%= f_video.name %></td>
      <td><%= f_video.date_added %></td>
      <td><%= f_video.views %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

`in_groups_of` has the added value/advantage that, when needed, it allows for padding any remaining slots with eg `'&nbsp;'`, which can be very useful. See the [docs](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Grouping.html).